# Copy image from REST to Blob using DataFacotry

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my scenario I need to consume an external REST api. One of the fields in the response is a url to an image. What I'm trying to achieve is to grab the pic behind that url and store it in the blob storage. This would be easy with a Function or WebJob but is there a way to do it with DataFactory on its own?

Comment: hi, does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research,only [Http Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http) supports downloading file which could be used in the copy activity as source dataset.

[image]

Comment: This is only about getting and nothing about storing. The answer is useful but not full so this is why I haven't marked it as answered.